# reset postgres PostgreSQL password remotely

Tags: postgresql, opensuse

I've found a number of sites that show how to reset a PostgreSQL password.

I can SSH into the machine, which is an OpenSuse 13.2 server, and I tried the commands that were given, and that never worked, I can't get into the psql in order to issue the SQL to change the password.

So, the pg_hba.conf has one line that looks like:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS           METHOD
host    all             postgres                         ident sameuser
```

Then I try to do a stop/start:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql stop
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

and then I get this error:

```
 Job for postgresql.service failed. See "systemctl status postgresql.service"  and "journalctl -xn" for details.
```

So, the database won't even start.

BTW, I know I could do:  /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
but I just wanted to know the database was really stopped before I restarted it.

I changed the pg_hba.conf file back to this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS             METHOD      
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             postgres                                trust
# IPv4 local connections: 
host    all             postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

And now I CAN START postgres again finally, so now I am going to try to login:

```
psql -U postgres
```

gives me:

```
psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" is not permitted to log in
```

By every web-site out there, this is supposed to work.   So, remotely over SSH or even on that machine, I still can't login to postgres, and I still can't change my password.

I need to get in and do this remotely, of if I have to be at the machine, I can do that also.

Comment: Have you checked ""systemctl status postgresql.service"  and "journalctl -xn" for details"?

Comment: This line `host all postgres ident sameuser` does't have any sense.
Type: host -> ok
Database: all -> ok
User: postgres -> ok
Address: ident -> fail
Method: sameuser -> fail

Comment: The database is restarting now ... I got it to start again.  Now the problem is how I can login as postgres to reset the password??????